# Rename-Items twice in the same pipeline using powershell

Tags: powershell, rename, pipeline

I'm trying to rename a bunch of files using powershell by removing the prefix (which is the same in all files), replacing "+" with a space and setting the remainder to title case. Here's what I have so far:

```
Where-Object { $_ -Match '^Website\.com_+' } |
ForEach-Object
{
    $_ |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace 'Website\.com_','' -replace '\+',' '};
    Rename-Item $_.Fullname (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($_)
}
```

The first rename works, it removes and formats files properly, but then the second rename says the items don't exist, which makes me think I should just then pass them into another foreach loop in another pipe, but I can't seem to make that work either.
It seems like having 2 rename-items isn't really working and I tried having the title case with the replace and it doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found something that works:

```
$path = "G:\Downloads\Chrome\test2"
$items = (Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File *.mp4 | 
Where-Object { $_ -Match '^Website\.com_+' } |
ForEach-Object{
    $_ |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace 'Website\.com_','' -replace '\+',' '} -PassThru
})
$items | % {
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName  -NewName (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($_.Name)
}
```

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me!

Answer (score 0):

It would be more straight forward to build the name in 2 stages and then do one `Rename-Item`
Something like below should do what you need

```
Where-Object { $_ -Match '^Website\.com_+' } |
ForEach-Object {
$BaseName = ($_.Name -replace 'website\.com','' -replace '\+','')
$FinalName = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($BaseName)
Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName $FinalName
}
```

Comment: This is telling me that there are illegal characters on the line with Rename-Item.

Comment: I cannot see what the exact error would be, but I think it really is trying to change the filename. The error is: Rename-Item : Illegal characters in path

Answer (score 0):

`$_` in your `ForEach-Object` loop is a snapshot of the item - it won't dynamically change to follow things you do to the underlying file. When you rename the item, `$_` represents the *old* name. So, when you attempt the second rename based on `$_.FullName`, `Rename-Item` won't find anything.

A potential solution to your problem of "setting the remainder to title case" would be, outside the loop, do another `Get-ChildItem` search for anything that falls into this condition, and then rename them separately.

Comment: I would like to choose items already in the pipeline, is that possible? Because I think a get-ChildItem would choose other files that share an extension that I wouldn't necessarily want to rename

Comment: The problem there is that it *looks* like your `ForEach-Object` loop catches all files you want to rename - it would seem that you have to have some other query to catch the rest?